# Ruby Sass returning color as name

Tags: ruby, sass

I have the following code to mix colours:

```
color = Sass::Script::Parser.parse("mix(#000000, #000000, 75%)", 0, 0).perform(Sass::Environment.new)
color.to_s
```

When the calculated colour is black, Sass uses the name `black`:

```
color => 'black'
```

I want it to be `#000000`. How do I do this?

I've even tried to change the style (as apparently compress mode causes this) e.g. `color = Sass::Script::Parser.parse("mix(#000000, #000000, 75%)", 0, 0, {:style => :nested}).perform(Sass::Environment.new)`

Currently we're having to handle this with:

```
color = hex_color_value(color)

def hex_color_value(sass_color)
  case sass_color
  when 'black'
    '#000000'
  when 'white'
    '#ffffff'
  else
    sass_color
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think that it's possible, [the parser seems to be converting it](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/a4b3e8c0c7073573cfd8df111eb25c8295851ebe/lib/sass/script/parser.rb#L503-L514) right away, but you can at least [use COLOR_NAMES constant](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/f31605339b4f4dd3098b010186db481b7563a634/lib/sass/script/value/color.rb#L42) to translate back.